# Access current document and display messagebox from agent called via lotusscript from UI

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, agents

I have an agent with the following code:

```
Sub Initialize
    MessageBox "AgentStart"
    Print "AgentStart"

    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim s As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim vItemsBySupplierSpec As NotesView
    Dim Doc As NotesDocument
    Dim DocsWithSameSupplierSpec As NotesDocumentCollection
    Dim MatchingDoc As NotesDocument
    Set Doc = ws.CurrentDocument.Document

    If Len(Doc.ItemSupplierSpecification(0)) > 0 Then
        ' Check that this supplier specification isn't use anywhere else.'
        Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
        Set vItemsBySupplierSpec = db.GetView("vItemsBySupplierSpec")

        Set DocsWithSameSupplierSpec = vItemsBySupplierSpec.GetAllDocumentsByKey(Doc.ItemSupplierSpecification(0), True)
        Set MatchingDoc = DocsWithSameSupplierSpec.GetFirstDocument

        Dim ItemsString As String

        ItemsString = "The following items already use this supplier specification." + Chr(10) + Chr(10) + _
        "You should check whether you really want to raise another, or use the existing one." + Chr(10)


        While Not MatchingDoc Is Nothing
            ItemsString = ItemsString + Chr(10) + MatchingDoc.ItemNumber(0) + " - " + MatchingDoc.ItemDescription(0)
            Set MatchingDoc = DocsWithSameSupplierSpec.GetNextDocument(MatchingDoc)
        Wend

        If DocsWithSameSupplierSpec.Count > 0 Then
            Print ItemsString
            MsgBox ItemsString
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Previously it was ran within the onchange event of a field in a form.

I've now created an agent as above, and want to invoke it from the ui both in lotus script and @formula language.

```
Dim s As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase

Set db = s.CurrentDatabase

Dim CheckSupplierSpec As NotesAgent
Set CheckSupplierSpec = db.GetAgent("CheckSupplierSpec")

If CheckSupplierSpec.Run = 0 Then
    MessageBox "Agent Ran"
End If
```

I created the agent as trigger, on event - menu selection, target: none, options: shared. I do get the "Agent Ran" messagebox.

I've tried this however although checking the agent it says it last ran when the `onchange` event was fired i don't get any message boxes or print output.

The first question, is why isn't the messagebox working? the 2nd question is how can i get the current document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help to know why you moved it from onChange to an agent, but I think there are ways to do what you want to do.

You mentioned invoking the agent from formula language- I was able to display a Messagebox calling the agent this way:

```
@Command([RunAgent];"CheckSupplierSpec")
```

Another option would be doing your agent as a Java agent. This gives you access to Java UI classes that will display even if called by NotesAgent.Run. Example [here](http://thinkgreat.blogspot.com/2008/04/messagebox-and-inputbox-easily-in-notes.html).

If you don't want to rework the entire agent in Java, you can use LS2J to access the Java UI classes. For example, you could create a Java script library called "Java Messagebox":

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class JavaMessagebox {

    public void Messagebox (String message) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    }

}
```

and then call it from a LotusScript agent like this:

```
Use "Java Messagebox"
Uselsx "*javacon"
Sub Initialize
    Dim mySession  As JavaSession
    Dim myClass As JavaClass
    Dim myObject As JavaObject
    Set mySession = New JavaSession()
    Set myClass = mySession.GetClass("JavaMessagebox")
    Set myObject = myClass.CreateObject()
    myObject.Messagebox(|This is my Java messagebox!|)
End Sub
```

For a more sophisticated example using a Java AWT component that uses the native look and feel of your operating system, I recommend studying [Julian Robichaux's LS2J Examples Database](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/NotesTips.htm#ls2jexamples). His StatusBox example is non-modal but you can find the parameter to make it modal [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html) if needed.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you lose context when you call an agent using the Run method. As the [designer help states](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_RUN_METHOD_6415.html):

> The user cannot interact directly with a called agent. User output goes to the Domino log.

You could try to pass the document's ID as a parameter to the run method instead:

```
Dim ws as New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim s As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase

Set db = s.CurrentDatabase

Dim CheckSupplierSpec As NotesAgent
Set CheckSupplierSpec = db.GetAgent("CheckSupplierSpec")

If CheckSupplierSpec.Run(ws.CurrentDocument.Document.NoteID) = 0 Then
    MessageBox "Agent Ran"
End If
```

That parameter is available to the agent in the ParameterDocID property:

http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/Main?OpenFrameSet

Comment: Thanks for that example, looks like that's the solution for getting the current doc. My first question though, is why isn't a message box being displayed. The first line of the agent should display one.

Comment: It kind of goes along with the fact that UI methods are not allowed when agents are run that way.  Presenting a messagebox or printing a statement would be a UI function.  You should, I think, see the message in the server logs, however.  It's either that, or the entire agent gets scanned for UI calls at onset, and doesn't even start if it contains any.  I vaguely remember that was the case with a bug I dealt with years ago, but don't quote me on it :)

Comment: Hmm, ok. That's annoying, but makes sense. Thanks again.